# sql query do in subquery in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

below is my SQL query

```
SELECT
         p.Name
       , p.DisplayName
       , (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM   LicenseActivations la
           WHERE  la.ProductId=p.Id
             AND la.AccountId='QWNjb3VudDo2N2YyMTcwMC0xMWZlLTExZWItYjNkMS0yN2U1Mjk0MGVhYmU='
         ) AS COUNT
FROM     [Products] p
GROUP BY p.Name, p.DisplayName, p.id;
```

here I am using two tables 1.Products 2.LicenseActivations, I need to form LINQ, Can anyone help me out with this one

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i need to form the linq query based on SQL subquery, My linqQuery not working

Comment: @IanNewson, he is asking how to express that SQL query in Linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linq you seldom need joins. With a proper database design with relations established, Linq navigation properties does the job (which are generated automatically by the tools for you):

```
var list = from p in _DbContext.Products
           select new {
              p.Name,
              p.DisplayName,
              Count = p.LicenseActivations.Count(x => x.AccountId=="QWNjb3VudDo2N2YyMTcwMC0xMWZlLTExZWItYjNkMS0yN2U1Mjk0MGVhYmU=")
           };
```

is the corresponding Linq query of your SQL (ToList() is optional).

EDIT: If you don't have proper relations in your database, then:

```
var list = from p in _DbContext.Products
           select new {
                  p.Name,
                  p.DisplayName,
                  Count = _DbContext.LicenseActivations
         .Count(x => x.ProductId == p.Id &&
   x.AccountId=="QWNjb3VudDo2N2YyMTcwMC0xMWZlLTExZWItYjNkMS0yN2U1Mjk0MGVhYmU=")
               };
```

Comment: here I am using two tables 1.Products 2.LicenseActivations, the above SQL QUERY IS WORKING correct but I need to form LINQ,

Comment: You need a predicate in the `Count()` I think

Comment: @user8837476, that Linq too is using two 'tables'. If you don't have proper relations in your database it needs to be written differently.

Comment: @CetinBasoz you need predicate for this part: `la.AccountId='QWNjb3VudDo2N2YyMTcwMC0xMWZlLTExZWItYjNkMS0yN2U1Mjk0MGVhYmU='`

Comment: @IanNewson, you are right I missed that restriction. Editing to add that.